# uneven color after boolean

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I use boolean to dig a hole in another model, but after that, the digging one's color is uneven on the edge. why? how can I fix that?

my file   https://pasteall.org/blend/2067f1d6b6104cddb5d30338c2ac928d

[image]

Comment: it's due to the shade smooth on bad topology, try to enable the Auto Smooth option in the Object Data panel > Normals, and tweak the Angle value, or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm just curious... Do you have two usernames or is it just coincidence that you and the user fatdrogen have similar meshes and try to do the same thing... while both using the same vocabulary like "digging a hole"? Or are you both working on the same kind of course at the same time?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann
yes, that account is on my office computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with the split normals (normals that determine the shading of the object), go into the Object Data panel > Geometry and click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* (and also keep the *Auto Smooth* option to keep a good shading):

[image]